# Insert an object inside an object using android room persistence library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-database, android-components

Directory

```
@Entity(tableName = "directory")
class Directory(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: Int? = null,
                @ColumnInfo(name = DIR_NAME) var dirName: String? = null,
                @Ignore var dirImages: List<Images>? = null

) : Serializable {
    companion object {
        const val DIR_NAME = "dirName"
        const val DIR_IMAGES = "dirImages"
    }
}
```

Image model

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = Directory::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)))

data class Images(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "image") val images: String
) {

}
```

Directory Dao

```
@Dao
interface DirectoryDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(directory: ArrayList<Directory>?)

}
```

How to insert list of images in directory?
Should I create a separate Dao for images?

Comment: The closest thing I can suggest is [@Transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction?authuser=4) annotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not make your list of Images a simple list of String ? (you can use typealias in kotlin if you want to stick to image)

You have 2 options, depending on how you need to access your **Image** Objects.
Are you okay to only get the list of Images from your **Directory** object or you do you need to some queries on your **images** in the DB? (such as count, findBy etc...)

**1st option**, if you just want to get your list of Images in your Directory object (probably the best for your case) :

```
@Entity(tableName = "directory")
class Directory(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: Int,
                @ColumnInfo(name = DIR_NAME) var dirName: String,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "images")
                @TypeConverters(ImagesConverters::class)
                 var dirImages: List<Images>)
```

where *ImagesConverters.kt* :

```
public class ImagesConverters {

    /**
     * Convert a a list of Images to a Json
     */
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromImagesJson(stat: List<Images>): String {
        return Gson().toJson(stat)
    }

    /**
     * Convert a json to a list of Images
     */
    @TypeConverter
    fun toImagesList(jsonImages: String): List<Images> {
        val notesType = object : TypeToken<List<Images>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson<List<Images>>(jsonImages, notesType)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add gson in your gradle file :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

In the your table "**Directory**", it will store the list of images directly into the col "**images**", in a json format.

**2nd option**, if you just want to a different table for your images and execute queries on them.

You will need to use a one to many relations and have 3 objects :

```
// directory.kt
@Entity(tableName = "directory")
class Directory(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: Int,
                @ColumnInfo(name = DIR_NAME) var dirName: String)


// image.kt
@Entity(tableName = "images")
class Image(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: Int,
            @ColumnInfo(name ="images") var image: String,
            @ColumnInfo(name ="directoryId") var directoryId: Int)

// directoryWithImages.kt
public class DirectoryWithImages {
   @Embedded
   public Directory directory;

   @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "directoryId", entity = Image.class)
   public List<Image> images;
}
```

And finally your dao :

```
@Dao
public interface LoadDirectoryWithImagesDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM directory")
    public List<DirectoryWithImages> loadDirectoriesWithImages();
}
```

Hope this help !

Comment: In addition to option 1,  type converters should also be declared on appdatabase -> @TypeConverters(ImagesConverters::class)

Comment: is DIR_NAME defined

Comment: Option 2: How to insert those objects to the db?

Comment: @Simon This would result in two separate inserts. First you insert the directory and then images ie: 

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertDirectory(directory: Directory)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertImages(images: List<Image>)